# ruby - interact with never-end child process

Tags: ruby, stdout, stdin, interaction, child-process

I wonder how can I interact with never-ending(eternal looping) child process.

source code of loop_puts.rb, child process :

```
loop do
    str = gets
    puts str.upcase
end
```

main.rb :

```
Process.spawn("ruby loop_puts.rb",{:out=>$stdout, :in=>$stdin})
```

I want to put some letter, not by my hand typing, and get result(not previous result) in variable.

how can I do this?

thanks

Comment: the looping process needs to read the letter from somewhere. maybe a socket, or something else.

Comment: I wonder if reading from $stdin is not a good idea. gets is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this and it's hard to recommend one without more context.

Here's one way using a forked process and a pipe:

```
# When given '-' as the first param, IO#popen forks a new ruby interpreter.  
# Both parent and child processes continue after the return to the #popen 
# call which returns an IO object to the parent process and nil to the child.
pipe = IO.popen('-', 'w+')
if pipe
  # in the parent process
  %w(please upcase these words).each do |s|
    STDERR.puts "sending:  #{s}"
    pipe.puts s   # pipe communicates with the child process
    STDERR.puts "received: #{pipe.gets}"
  end
  pipe.puts '!quit'  # a custom signal to end the child process
else
  # in the child process
  until (str = gets.chomp) == '!quit'
    # std in/out here are connected to the parent's pipe
    puts str.upcase
  end
end
```

Some documentation for [IO#popen here](http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/popen/class).  Note that this may not work on all platforms.

Other possible ways to approach this include [Named Pipes](https://github.com/dserban/I.GameBot/wiki/Named-Pipes-Example-in-Ruby), [drb](http://apidock.com/ruby/DRb), and [message queues](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs).